# IntegrityError on saving ImageField : Field 'path' doesn't have a default value

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a Model with an ImageField but i can't because it keeps giving me this error: **(1364, "Field 'path' doesn't have a default value")**

I tried to give that field a default value, save first the model then the field, and did not work.

**MODEL**

```
class Images360(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    oldpath = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/img/', null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**METHOD**

```
photo = Images360(name=filename,
    product=self.product,
    order=count
)
# photo.save()
photo.oldpath.save(filename, ContentFile(data))
```

**EDIT**
This have been working for months and it stopped working this week. I checked the files that are being uploaded and everything seems ok.

Comment: In the model I dont see the field `path` could please copy the complete model.

Comment: this is the complete model. I have to check if that  field has not been created into de ddbb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the table through SQL and the table showed a path column. So, somehow, this column was created. I deleted it, through migrations, and I solved the problem.